# Adding type="text/babel" stops the JS from working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am making an web application. The js file works perfectly fine when it is only js and not the babel syntax. But when I use text/babel with it it stops working.

This is what works:
`inbox.js` :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
  document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', send_email);
  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
});

function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

  // Clear out composition fields
  document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';
}

function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  //Load the emails
  show_email(mailbox);

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
}

function send_email(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        recipients: document.getElementById("compose-recipients").value,
        subject: document.getElementById("compose-subject").value,
        body: document.getElementById("compose-body").value
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      // Print result
      console.log(result);
      load_mailbox('sent');
  });
}

function show_email(mailbox) {
  fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {
      // Print emails
      console.log(emails);

      //render_email(email);

      // ... do something else with emails ...
  });
}
```

`inbox.html` :

```
{% block script %}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.9.4/babel.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/babel">
            function App() {
                return (
                <div>hello</div>
                );
            }
            function load() {
                ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("emails-view")).render(<App/>);
            }
            load();
    </script>
<script src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

But this doesn't work and it also stops the `js` file from working:

`inbox.html` :

```
{% block script %}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.9.4/babel.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/babel" src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script>
<!-- <script src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script> -->
{% endblock %}
```

`inbox.js` :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
  document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', send_email);
  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');
});

function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

  // Clear out composition fields
  document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';
}

function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  //Load the emails
  show_email(mailbox);

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
}

function send_email(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('/emails', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        recipients: document.getElementById("compose-recipients").value,
        subject: document.getElementById("compose-subject").value,
        body: document.getElementById("compose-body").value
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      // Print result
      console.log(result);
      load_mailbox('sent');
  });
}

function show_email(mailbox) {
  fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {
      // Print emails
      console.log(emails);

      //render_email(email);

      // ... do something else with emails ...
  });
}
function App() {
  return (
  <div>hello</div>
  );
}
function load() {
  ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("emails-view")).render(<App />);
}
load();
```

What's strange is it doesn't show any error in console. It just shows following warning:
babel.min.js:1

```
 You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/
(anonymous) @   babel.min.js:1
lH  @   babel.min.js:1
oH
enter code here
```

Comment: Why do you explicitly need to mention `type="text/babel"` ? Also I wonder if `text/babel` is a valid MIME type. [Read about script `type` attribute here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type)

Comment: As much as I know for a browser to know if this is babel syntax you need to add text/babel

Comment: As per my knowledge browser supports ES5 syntax and babel transpiles your ES6 code to ES5 so you don't have to explicitly mention type for your script. [Read about babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/).

Comment: What does `{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}` be at last? And When does these `{% xxx %}` be transformed?